# how to display same rows values in comma separated in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have table like this :

[image]

and I want to display gridview in c# using that table data like this :

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to databind a gridview or even that is a problem? If yes, then I can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have flat data then you need to do some transformation on the data and create another data table or collection to bind with the grid. See below example:

```
void Main()
{
//Let this Table
    List<SvrEnvApp> records = new List<SvrEnvApp>()
    {
        new SvrEnvApp(){
        Server = "server1",
        Env="FCT",
        App="A"
        },
        new SvrEnvApp(){
        Server = "server1",
        Env="UAT",
        App="B"
        },
        new SvrEnvApp(){
        Server = "server2",
        Env="FCT",
        App="A"
        },
        new SvrEnvApp(){
        Server = "server2",
        Env="UAT",
        App="B"
        }   
    };

    List<SvrEnvApp> result = records.GroupBy(o=> o.Server).Select(g=> new SvrEnvApp()
    {
        Server = g.Key,
        Env= String.Join(",",g.Select(r=> r.Env)),
        App= String.Join(",",g.Select(r=> r.App)),
    }).ToList();
    result.Dump();
}

public class SvrEnvApp
{
 public string Server{get;set;}
 public string Env{get;set;}
 public string App{get;set;}
}
```

Result: Transformed data to bind with the grid..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to databind gridview, you would get the gridview data using the query below. `StackoverflowTable3` is name of table I have used using your sample data and this query will return data as shown in screen shot below.

```
SELECT t1.Server,
   STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', '+t2.App
            FROM StackoverflowTable3 AS t2
            WHERE t1.Server = t2.Server
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '') AS [App],
   STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', '+t2.Env
            FROM StackoverflowTable3 AS t2
            WHERE t1.Server = t2.Server
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '') AS [Env]
FROM StackoverflowTable3 AS t1
GROUP BY t1.Server;
```

**Screenshot of data returned by above query**

[image: Data for gridview]

You can use gridview markup like below, if you are databinding to a `SqlDataSource`.

**Sample markup of gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True">
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Server" HeaderText="Server" SortExpression="Server" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Env" HeaderText="Env" SortExpression="Env" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="App" HeaderText="App" SortExpression="App" />
   </Columns>
   <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
   <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
   <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
   <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
   <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
   <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourDatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT t1.Server, STUFF(( SELECT ', '+t2.App  FROM StackoverflowTable3 AS t2 WHERE t1.Server = t2.Server FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS [App],
   STUFF((SELECT ', '+t2.Env FROM StackoverflowTable3 AS t2 WHERE t1.Server = t2.Server FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS [Env] FROM StackoverflowTable3 AS t1 GROUP BY t1.Server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i am using MS access as database and getting syntax error for stuff.